# How to auto fill date column by seconds?

Tags: excel

I have a cell in custom date time format (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000). When I drag this cell down to auto fill it, I have option to fill it with Days, months, Years, etc.

I want to drag this cell down to auto fill it with seconds/milli seconds. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure if this is what you are after, but you can add the following formula in A2 and auto-fill it down:

> =A1+0.00000001

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. That's exactly what i was trying to get and you made it quite easy for me.